# Probability distribution for transformation of a random variable

Tags: distributions, probability, random-variable

Let $g(x)=1$ if $x \leq c$ and $g(x)=(1-x)/(1-c)$, where $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and  $0 <c <1$.
So $g$ is an non-increasing function.

Define $g^{-1}(y)=\inf\{0 \leq x \leq 1 \mid g(x) \leq y\}$.

Now $X$ is a random variable that takes on value $0, 0.1, 0.2, \ldots, 1$.

Is it true that

$$
\mathbb P(g(X) \leq b) = \mathbb P(g^{-1} g(X) \geq g^{-1}(b)) \leq \mathbb P(X \geq g^{-1}(b)) \,?
$$

Comment: I've tried to typeset the math. Please make sure I haven't introduced errors in the process.

Comment: Is g$^-$^1$ monotonic non-decreasing?  If so it is true.

Comment: It should be g instead of f. Sorry for the typo. Just edited the problem. Thanks

Comment: I think g is monotone non-increasing.

Comment: **Related**: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/67320/7003 (But, with some work left for you to turn some of that information into something you can potentially use here.)

Comment: I believe your definition of $g^{-1}$ is incorrect. For any $y\in [0,1]$, $g^{-1}(y) = 0$ with the definition you've given.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing it out, Cardinal. I have made the correction in the problem. --- Hannah

Comment: I think the argument is correct. By definition, $g^{-1}(g(x)) = inf\{t: g(t) \leq g(x)\}$. Also $x \in \{t: g(t) \leq g(x)\}$. Hence $g^{-1}(g(x)) \leq x, \quad \forall x \in [0,1]$. Therefore we have $g^{-1}(g(X)) \leq X$ and we have the "less than or equal" sign in the problem. Please correct me if this argument is not right. Thanks.